# Wordpress: Disable part of Jquery function on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I simply want to disable the below function on mobile. Here is a [Pen](http://codepen.io/ssosina/pen/zZmQXM). It works but when I resize my browser the hover effect doesn't work as desired (`<img>` hangs at the bottom of the `h2` element. the desired effect is for the `<img>` to follow the mouse cursor).

**jQuery**

```
if ( jQuery(window).width() > 769) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      jQuery('.article__title').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(evt){
          jQuery(this).siblings('.article__img').css({left: evt.pageX+30, top: evt.pageY-200}).show();
          jQuery(this).on('mouseleave', function(){
              jQuery(this).siblings('.article__img').hide();
          });
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `jQuery(window).width() > 769` is `false` then the code inside of it will never run. If it's `true` then it will. When you open the pen you'll most likely have a wide enough `window`. But that code runs once when the page loads and that's it. Resizing the window doesn't mean that code runs again, and even if it did you wouldn't want to call those functions multiple times.

What you need is to apply that condition inside `jQuery('.article__title').on('mouseenter mousemove', function(evt){` so that it's checked every time you move the mouse.

Comment: Damn. Thats so true :(  Thanks I will give it a go now.